# Configure Makefile

Tags: macos, bash, make, gcc, makefile

I am trying to create a file `Makefile` to use with `make` so I can compile my codes faster.
What I would like to do is just type in the terminal:

```
make dev myOutputName
```

And it should run:

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 dev.c -o myOutputName
```

So far I have the following `Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 -Wno-unused-result
CC = gcc

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<  -o $\dev
```

First, is that correct above?
I tested it and it compiles, but the output name is always `dev`.

How can I change it so I can type:

```
make dev myOutputName
```

And it will run:

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 dev.c -o myOutputName
```

Comment: You are explicitly setting the output to be dev (`-o $\dev`).

Comment: How do I change it?

Comment: Set it to `-o myOutputName` just as you do when running manually.

Comment: @terdon There is no way I can type: `make dev "random name` that it will run: `gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 dev.c -o "random name"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a Makefile for this, you could use a bash function. Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
function mkdev(){
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 $1 -o $2
}
```

Then, `source ~/.bashrc` (it is easy enough to port to other shells if you are not using bash) or simply open a new terminal and you can compile your code with

```
mkdev dev myOutputName
```

In `bash`, `$1`, `$2` , ... , `$N` are the arguments given to a program or function. So, the function above takes the 1st argument and looks for a file with that name and a `.c` extension and the second argument is the output name.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thks man!! One more question @terdon, what does `source ~/.bashrc` do? What is the `source` command for?

Comment: Glad to have helped, just to clarify, the `source` command forces `bash` to reread `.bashrc` and so load your changes. Starting a new bash session (opening a new terminal) will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

`make` does not take a list of arguments. It takes a list of targets. You can set variables from the invoking command, though

```
make O=myOutputName dev
```

In the Makefile:

```
%: %.c
       gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 $< -o $(O)
```